# flutter: pass FAB click listener to Tabbar widget

Tags: android, flutter, interface, floating-action-button, tabbar

I have a home screen with tabbar and FAB buttons. I need to pass FAB click listener to my tabbar widget in flutter. But I can't find any way to how to achieve this. I am new to flutter. Someone, please help me to find out a solution.

here is my `HomeScreen` tabbar and I want  to pass click of FAb to `MyContactTab.dart`

```
     ...
        child: TabBarView(
          children: [
            ChatTab().buildChatScreen(),
            GroupTab().buildGroupScreen(),
            MyContactsTab(permissionStatus: _permissionStatus)
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
        ), 
    ...
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        //should call MyContactTab's onRefreshClick()
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.sync,
      ),
    ),
```

this is `MyContactTab.dart`

```
class MyContactsTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final PermissionStatus permissionStatus;

  MyContactsTab({Key key, @required this.permissionStatus});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyContactState(permissionStatus);
  }
}

class MyContactState extends State<MyContactsTab>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<MyContactsTab> {
  void onRefreshClick() {
    //todo refresh contacts
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to make use of one of the Model-View-Controller variants. The [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package is a popular choice. It essentially breaks the model up into blocs. You can get a handle to a bloc via the FAB build context. You can register the bloc in the widget tree above the FAB and MyContactTab. In the FAB onPressed() callback, you retrieve the bloc via the context then use it to update the state used by MyContactTab. The build method of MyContactTab can listen for bloc state updates and rebuild in response.

That may seem involved, but it is clean and maintainable. You might be able to do something with GlobalKeys to get a handle on a specific widget from the FAB, but transferring state between widgets with uncertain lifetimes is not easy to reason about or maintain.